How to concate string in solidity?
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.26;

contract HiName {
    string public name;

    constructor(string memory _name) {
        name = _name;
    }

    function Hi(string calldata _yourname) public view returns (string memory) {
        return name + _yourname;
    }
}

